# Sum of series using standard results

Tags: sequences-and-series

It may be appropriate to show the rest of the question, as results may come from it: http://gyazo.com/0a9d3dc38f0748bae3183c0b71c2003d

My question is:

Find the sum of the series:

$$1^2 + 2\cdot2^2 + 3^2 + 2\cdot4^2 + 5^2 + 2\cdot6^2 + \cdots + 2(n-1)^2 + n^2$$

Where $n$ is odd.

I know these are two series in the form
$$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2 + n^2$$
And
$$2^2 + 4^2 + 6^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2$$
But I do not know how to carry on from here, and I do not understand the 'where $n$ is odd', when clearly the first series includes even numbers, or if maybe it means the last number is odd. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it means that the last number $n$ is odd. Otherwise, the "pattern" hinted at by the "..." makes no sense.

Comment: How does it affect in any way the final result?

Comment: I recommend that you read a bit about summing squares here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

Comment: It allows there to ***be*** a final result, in the first place, as it isn't well-defined, otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Since $n$ is odd, let's write it as $n=2m+1.$

Now, use the fact that $$1^2+2^2+\cdots+k^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}6,$$ and observe that $$\begin{align}2^2+4^2+6^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2 &= (2\cdot1)^2+(2\cdot 2)^2+(2\cdot 3)^2+\cdots+(2m)^2\\ &= 4\cdot 1^2+4\cdot 2^2+4\cdot 3^2+\cdots+4\cdot m^2\\ &= 4\cdot(1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+m^2)\end{align}$$ and $m=\frac{n-1}2.$

From this, you should be able to find the sum in terms of $n.$

Answer (score 1):

To understand why we require that $\rm n$ is odd look closely at the following:

$$\rm \color{red}1^2 + 2\cdot\color{blue}2^2 + \color{red}3^2 + 2\cdot\color{blue}4^2 + \color{red}5^2 + 2\cdot\color{blue}6^2 + \cdots + 2\color{blue}{(n-1)}^2 + \color{red}n^2.\tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$

We could easily require that $\rm n$ be even but then our expression would have taken the form: $$\rm 1^2 + 2\cdot2^2 + 3^2 + 2\cdot4^2 + 5^2 + 2\cdot6^2 + \cdots + 2n^2 + (n+1)^2\tag{$\star$}$$

For the sum write $\rm n$ as $\rm 2k+1$ to simplify your expression $(\diamondsuit)$, and as $\rm 2k$ if you want to use the expression $(\star)$. After rearranging, you should identify two sums involving squares, to find them use the fact that: $$\rm \sum_{\mathop i=0}^n i^2=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Let's $\ds{S_{\ell} \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{\ell}}$:

> \begin{align}
> \color{#c00000}{S_{3}}&=\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{3}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\pars{k + 1}^{3}
> =1 + \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k + 1}^{3} - \pars{n + 1}^{3}
> \\[3mm]&=\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k^{3} + 3k^{2} + 3k + 1} + 1 - \pars{n + 1}^{3}
> =\color{#c00000}{S_{3}} + 3S_{2} + 3S_{1} + S_{0}  + 1 - \pars{n + 1}^{3} 
> \end{align}

The $\ds{\color{#c00000}{\mbox{red sums}\ S_{3}}}$ cancels such that:
\begin{align}
S_{2}&=\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2}
={\pars{n + 1}^{3} - 1 \over 3} -\
\overbrace{S_{1}}^{\ds{=\ {n\pars{n + 1} \over 2}}}\ - {1 \over 3}\
\overbrace{S_{0}}^{\ds{=\ n}}
={2n^{3} + 6n^{2} + 6n - 3n^{2} -3n - 2n  \over 6}
\\[3mm]&={2n^{3} + 3n^{2} + n\over 6}
\quad\imp\quad\color{#00f}{\large%
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2} = {n\pars{n + 1}\pars{2n + 1} \over 6}}
\end{align}

> In general, $\ds{S_{\ell}}$ is a linear combination of
>   $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\ n-\mbox{dependent coefficients}~}}$
>   $\ds{S_{\ell -1},S_{\ell - 2},\ldots,S_{0}}$ plus a $\ds{n}$-dependent factor such that they can be calculated recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by determining what $S(n) = 1^2+2^2+...+n^2$ is:

Note, we want to guess a formula and then induct. So, $S(1) = 1$, $S(2) = 5$, $S(3) = 14$, $S(4) = 30$. We see that a factor of $\frac{2n+1}{3}$ crops in. This leaves a factor of $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ left over. Hence, $S(n) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. We prove this inductively. Note that $S(1) = 1$ and $S(n+1) = S(n) + (n+1)^2 = (n+1)\cdot [\frac{2n^2+n}{6} + n+1] = (n+1)\cdot [{2n^2+7n+6}{6}] = (n+1)\cdot \frac{(2n+3)(n+2)}{6} = S(n+1).$

Now your sum is $$S(n) + 4\cdot S(\frac{n-1}{2}) \\
= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} + 4\cdot \frac{(n-1)(n+1)(n)}{24} \\
= \frac{n(3n^2+3n)}{6} \\
= \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to solve the problem directly by using indefinite sums from discrete calculus. Recall that we have:
$$
    \sum_x x^{\underline{k}} = \frac{1}{k+1}x^{\underline{k+1}} + C
$$
where
$$
    x^{\underline{k}} = x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k+1)
$$

Now you need to derive formula for the sum of squares.
$$
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \dots + n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2.
$$

The fundamental theorem of descrete calculus states:
$$
\sum_{k=a}^b f(k) = \left [ \sum_x f(x) \right]_{x=a}^{b+1}
$$

Let's find $\sum_x x^2$:

$$
\sum_x x^2 = \sum_x x(x-1) + x = \sum_x x^{\underline{2}} + x^{\underline{1}}
 = \frac13x^{\underline{3}} + \frac12x^{\underline{2}} + C =\\
 = \frac13x(x-1)(x-2) + \frac12x(x-1) + C
 = \frac16x(x-1)(2x-1) + C
$$

Finally:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \left [ \frac16x(x-1)(2x-1) \right]_{x=1}^{n+1}
    = \frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)
$$

With this formula you can solve the problem as shown in other answers.